# Allow user select role in wordpress default registration without plugin

Tags: functions, user-roles, user-registration, wp-register-script

How do I allow user select role, like 'Contributor' and 'Subscriber' In Default Wordpress Registration Page Without Plugin

Comment: Set the New User Default Role in Settings -> General. This is not a development question.

Comment: Did you mean let the user choose the role themselves when they register? That doesn't sound sensible to me, at least not without approval from an administrator too.